# Select rows in pandas dataframe between dates, regardless of year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a datetime index. For simplicity, let's say my data goes from September 1, 2016 to September 1, 2019, with each row corresponding to a day.

I would like to select all rows where the date is between November 15 and March 15, regardless of the year. For my example dataset, this would be: November 15, 2016 - March 15, 2017, November 15, 2017 - March 15, 2018, and November 15, 2018 - March 15, 2019.

It's very simple to select rows between 2 datetimes (when the year is known), but I can't think of a simple way to do this when we don't care about the year. Ideally, I would like to set this up where I can easily change the start and end dates of my range (instead of starting on November 15, I could start on November 21, etc).

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: What I would is create an extra column that takes the values of `df['monthdate'] = str(month)+str(day)` and then use that column as filter. Share you dataframe, what have you tried and what the error has been so we can help you! Take a read at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-09-01','2019-09-01', freq='D')})

# dummy variable for filter
s = df['date'].dt.month * 100 + df['date'].dt.day

# filter out the day between 3/16 and 11/14:
df[~s.between(316,1114)].head()
```

Output:

```
         date
75 2016-11-15
76 2016-11-16
77 2016-11-17
78 2016-11-18
79 2016-11-19
```

Comment: `s = df.date.dt.strftime('%m%d').astype(int)` is an alternative.  Fantastic answer!